# Bloom with Pip Test Depend

Tags: ros, pip, bloom-release, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to bloom a package to indigo with `bloom-release 0.6.2`

The package has a `test_depend` on `python-gitpython-pip` a.k.a. [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) but it is installed via pip. From [rosdep](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml)...

```
python-gitpython-pip:
  ubuntu:
    pip:
      packages: [gitpython]
```

When I bloom the package, I get the following error.

```
Pre-verifying Debian dependency keys...
Running 'rosdep update'...
Key 'python-gitpython-pip' resolved to '['gitpython']' with installer 'pip', which does not match the default installer 'apt'.
Failed to resolve python-gitpython-pip on ubuntu:trusty with: Error running generator: The Debian generator does not support dependencies which are installed with the 'pip' installer.
python-gitpython-pip is depended on by these packages: ['ros_introspection']
<== Failed
Some of the dependencies for packages in this repository could not be resolved by rosdep.
You can try to address the issues which appear above and try again if you wish.
Would you like to try again? [Y/n]? n
```

I feel like I should still be able to generate a Debian since it is only a `test_depend`. What's the best way around this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280855/bloom-with-pip-test-depend/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When building packages the test dependencies are encoded into the debian control files to allow running tests using the debian/dpkg tools. (Actually all binary builds also run the tests before packaging) We don't gate the build on the tests passing but they are tested and there's a log of the result. And part of that is that we don't currently install the test dependencies before running the tests at the moment so almost all of them fail.

There's an open ticket on bloom about this: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/292

In the long run I think that we should be following the debian approach and run the unit tests when packaging and only consider it successfully packaged if the unit tests pass. And to do that we will want to have the test dependencies available. So I'd rather not relax the constraint that dependencies need to be available as debian packages for the debian bloom generator.

For your use case I'd suggest that you could simply patch out that dependency in the release repository and then when bloom ran the generator the test dependency would not be encountered.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-01-26**:
Thanks TF!